# Countable family of finite sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3.....$ be a countable family of finite sets. Then
$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is countable.

My definition of countable excluded finiteness. I.e A set is countable if it is denumerable.

My proof:
As each $A_i$ is finite, we can write down its elements as 
($a_{i1}$,$a_{i2}$…$a_{im_{i}})$

Let $f:\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined as 
f($a_{ij}$) $=$ $2^{i}3^{j}$. The map is injective by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Furthermore, as $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, so is the union.

Is the proof correct?

EDIT:
PLEASE PROVIDE AN ALTERNATIVE PROOF

Comment: Your statement is not true assuming your definition of countability.  If the sets were all identical, the infinite union would be finite.

Comment: @MatthewDaly they can't be identical. As $(A_i)$ is a countable family.

Comment: Terms of families don't need to be distinct.

Comment: @MatthewDaly So, if in addition to the hypothesis, I assume that they are distinct. Would my proof work?

Comment: If the sets are all disjoint, then definitely yes.  If not, then you have the problem that maybe $a_{11}=a_{21}$, and you are giving those elements different indices by $f$ even though they only contribute to the union once.  I'm not quite certain how to fix your proof in this case, although the conclusion is definitely true.

Comment: Your proof shows that the union is either countable or finite.  Then it would just take a line or two to show that if the union were finite (say $n$ elements), there couldn't have been more than $2^n$ distinct sets that would have that union, so the union couldn't be finite by contradiction.

Comment: @MatthewDaly could you, if you may, write a correct proof, please?

Comment: Words are words.  In my opinion Countable should include finite but if doesn't so be it.  A countable unit of finite sets is finite or countable.  Yes we can prove that a countable union of dijoint sets is countable/no finite but I think the condition the sets be disjoint is way too restrictive to be practical. (That wouldn't allow anything like $A_n=\{$ prime divisors of $n\}$ for example.) And the exception that the union could be finite is *not* a show-stopper.

Comment: Hmmm... that condition the sets be *distinct* and the argument that a finite union means finite distinct sets though *is* valid and useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, we are assuming that the sets are all distinct (but not necessarily disjoint).

We can show that the union $U$ is not finite by contradiction.  If it were, then we could let $n$ be the number of elements in the union.  But there are only $2^n$ distinct subsets that could have $U$ as their union. Since $(A_i)$ is actually infinite, we have reached a contradiction.

Your proof works if all the terms of $(A_i)$ are disjoint.  So, in a sense, you have shown that the union cannot be uncountable even in "the worst case".  Therefore, the union must be countable.

Comment: Where does it break down, if im not assuming the terms to be disjoint?

Comment: @topologicalmagician You said it was a countable family.

Comment: @topologicalmagician The domain of your family is the union.  If the sets were not disjoint, the some $x$ in the union would be in two different sets.  This would make $f$ give multiple outputs for that same input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your proof is correct provided that we have a countable family of disjoint sets. You have defined an injective function from the union into the set of natural  numbers which in turn defines a one to one correspondent between the union and a subset of natural numbers.

Thus the union is countable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May you please add your thoughts on what has been written in the comment section, please?

Comment: If you count finite sets as countable then the concerns will go away.

Comment: No, my class doesnt. Unfortunately.

Comment: @topologicalmagician If you have a countable  family of disjoint finite sets then there would not be any problems.